# ldap connection to active directory from React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do a webpage in React, I need to login against an existing Active Directory.
I'm using ldapjs, (npm install ldapjs), the callback Login button is:

```
async login(){
    console.log('Login');
    var ldapjs = require('ldapjs')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const ldapClient = ldapjs.createClient({url: 'ldap://...'}, 
          (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR")
            return reject(err);
          }
          console.log("OK")
          return resolve(res);
        })
    })
  }
```

I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: net.connect is not a functionclient.js:1035
    Preact 2
        connectSocket
        connect
    apply self-hosted:1868
    Preact 2
        emit
        onBackoff_
     self-hosted:867

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [ldapjs](https://github.com/ldapjs/node-ldapjs) is a **server** side module, designed to be used in NodeJS. You can't use it in the browser on the client side, only server side.

If you look at the official site [here](http://ldapjs.org/), you can see (above the code snippet) that it specifically says it's for use in Node.

Comment: Thank for the reply,
  Do you know what I can use to make this connection?

Comment: @oolv I don't, sorry. I tried Googling around about "client side ldap" stuff, but the info is pretty sparse, leading me to believe that it should ideally be done server side. But I'll let you explore that stuff. Best of luck